# When an android application starts a service, does it runt in a different process

Tags: android

When an android application starts a service, does it runt in a different process or same process? I think it is run in the same process as the android application. Is that correct?

But from the O'Reilly Efficient Android Threading book , page 9, it said

"The Activity offloads work to a Service that runs in process P2, which starts the
Service and the associated Application instance. Therefore, the application has split
the work into two different processes. The P1 Activity can terminate while the P2
Service keeps running."

I just dont' understand how can 'the application has split
the work into two different processes'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think it is run in the same process as the android application. Is that correct?

By default, yes.

> I just dont' understand how can 'the application has split the work into two different processes'?

Well, I don't have that book, so I cannot state specifically what they are referring to.

However, it is entirely possible to have [an `android:process` attribute in a `<service>`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html#proc) to indicate that the service should run in another process. This usually is not necessary.